# Aspell PIL can't install with setup.py Python 3

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Terminal Error Return

```
root@sys:~/Downloads/PIL-fork-1.1.7-py3# python3 setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'PIL._imaging' extension
gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -fPIC -IlibImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python3.2mu -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.2/_imaging.o
_imaging.c:75:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
root@sys:~/Downloads/PIL-fork-1.1.7-py3#
```

this file are downloaded from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil
how to install this Aspell PIL Python 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following below step to complete install PIL

```
sudo aptitude install python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
download the Pillow-master.zip
wget https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/archive/master.zip
go to downloaded directory and,
sudo unzip Pillow-master.zip
python3 setup.py build
python3 setup.py install
```